# QuickLook process has a file open multiple times

Tags: macos, quicklook

I was cleaning up my Mac (on El Capitan 10.11.2), and I tried to delete some obscure old Word file. When I clicked on "empty trash", it gave me the message that the file was being used. I didn't know what was using it, and didn't want to cause problems, so I used `lsof | grep /Users/myusername/.Trash` and found that the QuickLook process had it open 12 times! Should I delete the file? Why on earth does Quick Look have it open at all?

PS: I quick-looked the file again and ran `lsof | grep -c /Users/myusername/.Trash`, which told me that it was then open 18 times, in case that helps.

Answer (score 1):

[Try running `qlmanage -r`. This should reload QuickLook and make it so it's no longer focused on those files](https://superuser.com/questions/125841/how-can-i-free-files-that-are-in-use-by-quicklook). You can also try using something like [Trash It!](http://nonamescriptware.com/downloads/) if after restarting and relaunching/killing Finder and QuickLook does nothing.

Comment: Yeah, I'll just use `rm` eventually. I'm kind of just curious as to why this might happen.